# I don't think my code has put g++ says there is?

Tags: c++, macos, opengl, clang++

so I'm using GLFW and VSCode and have written:

```
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main(void)
{
    GLFWwindow* window;

    if (!glfwInit())
        return -1;

    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Hello World", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

I used g++ to compile this and entered `g++ main.cpp -o build -Wall -framework OpenGL -L/usr/local/Cellar/glfw/3.3.2/lib` And its output was

```
ld: warning: text-based stub file /System/Library/Frameworks//OpenGL.framework/OpenGL.tbd and library file /System/Library/Frameworks//OpenGL.framework/OpenGL are out of sync. Falling back to library file for linking.
ld: warning: text-based stub file /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGLU.tbd and library file /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGLU.dylib are out of sync. Falling back to library file for linking.
ld: warning: text-based stub file /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGL.tbd and library file /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGL.dylib are out of sync. Falling back to library file for linking.
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_glfwCreateWindow", referenced from:
      _main in main-2fb2c9.o
  "_glfwInit", referenced from:
      _main in main-2fb2c9.o
  "_glfwMakeContextCurrent", referenced from:
      _main in main-2fb2c9.o
  "_glfwPollEvents", referenced from:
      _main in main-2fb2c9.o
  "_glfwSwapBuffers", referenced from:
      _main in main-2fb2c9.o
  "_glfwTerminate", referenced from:
      _main in main-2fb2c9.o
  "_glfwWindowShouldClose", referenced from:
      _main in main-2fb2c9.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I installed GLFW 3 with homebrew. I'm on macOS High Sierra 10.13.6 And VSCode version: 1.48.2
Commit: a0479759d6e9ea56afa657e454193f72aef85bd0
Date: 2020-08-25T10:09:08.021Z
Electron: 7.3.2
Chrome: 78.0.3904.130
Node.js: 12.8.1
V8: 7.8.279.23-electron.0
OS: Darwin x64 17.7.0
Thanks in advance!

Comment: It seems that the fist warning line is crucial. There seems to be something broken with the OpenGL installation. Just a shot in the dark: Check if you have the release or development version installed. And please try to write a better title for your question, as is it's very confusing, and not very informative.

Comment: You’re not linking with the glfw library. `-L` says where to look for libraries, but not what libraries to look for.

Comment: **homebrew** links everything into `/usr/local/lib` so IMHO you'd be better off using that than the version-specific path you've chosen - else you won't benefit from upgrades. Try `ls -l /usr/local/lib/*glfw*` to see symlinks.

Comment: Try `g++ main.cpp -o build -Wall -L/usr/local/Cellar/glfw/3.3.2/lib -lglfw3 -framework OpenGL`